# Проблема с функцией abs() в С++

Tags: c++, c, математика, visual-c++, арифметика

Имеется код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\tЧисло\t\tРешение" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (double i = -4.0; i <= 4.0; i += 0.5) {
        cout << "\t" << i << "\t\t" << abs(i - 2.0) + abs(i + 1.0) << endl;
    }
    cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Функция abs должна вернуть числа с плавающей точкой. А возвращаются целочисленными, вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Замена abs на fabs (что бы это не значило) не помогает.
Замена math.h на cmath тоже не помогает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы просто подобрали числа так, что получаются значения типа ###.000.

Возьмите другой шаг — и увидите то, что хотите :)

Смотрите...

```
abs(i - 2.0) + abs(i + 1.0)
```

При `i >= 2` имеем значение `2*i - 1`. Для целых и полуцелых чисел результат целый.

При  `2 > i > -1` получаем результат `3`. Тоже целое для любых `i`.

При `i < -1` имеем `1 - 2*i` — что опять же для целых и полуцелых чисел дает целочисленный результат...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Взгляните: https://ideone.com/yWAtIE